# AS3 Pass parameter by value

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

im having problems with the following code:

```
for (var i:Number=0; i<numFaces;i++){
    var faceLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    faceLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.INIT, 
    function(fle:Event){
        LoadCara(i,faceLoader);
        trace("LoadCara:" + i.toString());
    } );
}

function LoadCara(index:int,loader:Loader){
  if(index == 0)
  {
    trace("cara1:" + index.toString());
    cara1.removeChildAt(0);
    cara1.addChild(loader);
  }
  else if(index == 1)
  {
    cara2.removeChildAt(0);
    cara2.addChild(loader);
  }}
```

The problem is that im sending the variable i to the function LoadCara on every iteration, and its always called with the last value of i. I would like this function to be called with the appropiate index.

Hope I explain myself, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not about "passing parameters by value" or not. The event handler function that you declare does not access the `i` variable as a parameter at all. That's why the value of `i` is not determined by the for loop.

There are a couple of ways to deal with this situation. You can either create a new class that extends Event, and add your index value there.

OR you can create an array and store the faceLoaders with the index that you need. And then call LoadCara() with the correct index by looking up the matching index in the array.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to achieve [what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431230/generic-events-and-additional-parameters-in-actionscript-3-0/1438392#1438392)
it's not always advisable but sometimes handy...

Answer (score 0):

The content of the function belongs to the function, don't use variables from outside of it. Like `cara1` and `cara2`, that `i` doesn't belong to the function where you're using it.

But to fix your code is simple:

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < numFaces; i++) {
  var fLoader:Loader = new Loader();
  fLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, LoadCara(i, fLoader));
  trace("LoadCara:" + i.toString());
}

function LoadCara(index:int, loader:Loader):Function {
  return function(fle:Event):void {
    if (index == 0) {
      trace("cara1:" + index.toString());
      cara1.removeChildAt(0);
      cara1.addChild(loader);
    } else if (index == 1) {
      cara2.removeChildAt(0);
      cara2.addChild(loader);
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to be able to use `removeEventListener()` later, adjust the loop to:

```
var functionsLoadCara:Object = new Object();
for (var i:Number = 0; i < numFaces; i++) {
  var fLoader:Loader = new Loader();
  functionsLoadCara[i] = LoadCara(i, fLoader);
  fLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, functionsLoadCara[i]);
  trace("LoadCara:" + i.toString());
}
```

Then, when you don't need the event listener anymore, do:

```
for (var i:Number = 0; i < numFaces; i++) {
 fLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.INIT, functionsLoadCara[i]);
}
```

This way to pass your parameters is safer. It's exemplified better in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13488640).