# Main mxml file and as file - how to exchange data

Tags: actionscript, flex4, flash-builder

I have a main mxml file and a phpconnect.as file. When I call the phpconnect-function from the mxml-file the connect works fine also trace in the console works fine. But what's the best way to get the results of the phpconnect.as file back to the mxml-file.

Here's the code
main mxml Test02HomeView.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Platzieren Sie nichtvisuelle Elemente (z. B. Dienste, Wertobjekte) hier -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import comps.PHPConnect;

            protected function phpConnect_btn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                var phpconnect:PHPConnect = new PHPConnect();
                phpconnect.phpconnect();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:TextArea id="log_txt" x="10" y="128" height="104"/>
    <s:Button id="phpConnect_btn" x="180" y="256" width="130" label="PHPConnect" click="phpConnect_btn_clickHandler(event)"/>

</s:View>
```

Here's the code from the phpconnect.as

```
package comps
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.HTTPStatusEvent;
    import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class PHPConnect
    {
        public function PHPConnect()
        {
        }


        public function phpconnect():void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            configureListeners(loader);

            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/file.php");
            try {
                loader.load(request);
            } catch (error:Error) {
                trace("Unable to load requested data.");
            }

        }

        private function configureListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void
        {
            dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.OPEN, openHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);
            dispatcher.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
        }

        private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
            var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
            trace("completeHandler: " + loader.data);
            // log_txt.text = loader.data;
        }

        private function openHandler(event:Event):void {
            trace("openHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function progressHandler(event:ProgressEvent):void {
            trace("progressHandler loaded:" + event.bytesLoaded + " total: " + event.bytesTotal);
        }

        private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
            trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function httpStatusHandler(event:HTTPStatusEvent):void {
            trace("httpStatusHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
            trace("ioErrorHandler: " + event);
        }


    }
}
```

Think for someone who uses actionscript and FlashBuilder, this could be a simple question.
For me solving this would be great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom event class following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431230/generic-events-and-additional-parameters-in-actionscript-3-0) and dispatch it when your `PHPConnect` class has successfully loaded the data which you can pass as a property of the event. You can now subscribe to that event in your main mxml class and access the loaded data via the event object.

Alternatively / additionally you could set the data as the value of a public property of the `PHPConnect` class and access it via the instance instead of via the event object.

**Test02HomeView.mxml:**

```
protected function phpConnect_btn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    var phpconnect:PHPConnect = new PHPConnect();
    phpconnect.addEventListener(CustomEvent.LOADED, this.dataLoadedHandler);
    phpconnect.phpconnect();
}

private function dataLoadedHandler(event:CustomEvent):void
{
    trace("Data loaded:", event.data);

    // Or, assuming instance of phpconnect is in scope and has public data property
    //trace("Data loaded:", phpconnect.data);
}
```

**PhpConnect.as:**

```
private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {
    //var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
    trace("completeHandler: " + data);
    // log_txt.text = loader.data;

    // Don't need to create a new instance of loader, just cast the target property
    // Now dispatch a custom event with the data as the payload
    dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.LOADED, URLLoader(event.target).data));
}
```